# Parse log file with Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

Im a newbie to hadoop. I did the setup and executed the basic word count java program. The results look good.

My question is it possible to parse an extremely big log file to fetch only a few required lines using the map/reduce classes? Or is some other step required?

Any pointers in this direction will be very useful.
Thanks, Aarthi

Comment: I really doubt Hadoop will be of much use if your log file is store on a single computer. The story might be a bit different if it is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is entirely possible, and if the file is sufficiently large, I believe hadoop could prove to good way to tackle it, despite what nhahtdh says.

Your mappers could simply act as the filters - check the values passed to them, and only if they fit the conditions of a required line do you `context.write()` it out.

You wont even need to write your own reducer, just use the default `reduce()` in the `Reducer` class.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input. Would you happen to know of any examples? I have seen the word count/anagram/sorting examples, but something like parsing the log?

Comment: Don't know of any examples showing exactly what you're after, but it is hardly complex. In your mappers, simply parse the text object (which will be one line from your log file if you use `TextInputFormat` for your job) as you see fit to extract what you need, and simply write it out.

Comment: Aarthi, it would be good if you could share some sample log lines so that the problem is better understood. Any way to answer the question - how muchever big your file be, based on your hadoop infrastructure, Log parsing is possible with hadoop.